# Как добавить "Загрузку ЦП" на диспетчер задач?

Tags: c#, cpu

Нужно вывести на Label цифры загрузки ЦП. Как это сделать?

```
private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {                             }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c

Comment: А подробней можно? Куда кого что? Я это и сам нашел

Comment: Используйте класс `PerformanceCounter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раздел `using`

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Можно создать класс:

```
public static class CompPerformance
{
    static PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    static PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

    public static string getCurrentCpuUsage()
    {
        return cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
    }

    public static string getAvailableRAM()
    {
        return ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB";
    }
}
```

В форме вызов:

```
private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Text = CompPerformance.getCurrentCpuUsage();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Для постоянного(не ручного) обновления можно воспользоваться таймером в панели инструментов конструктора формы находим в разделе компоненты `Timer`, кидаем его на форму, задаём интервал срабатывания в миллисекундах, включаем его, а в привязанный метод к событию срабатывания `Tick` добавляем:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Text = CompPerformance.getCurrentCpuUsage();
}
```

Что-то типа того...

Comment: Ага, теперь выдает, но по щелчку на этот ноль) Щелкаю - он обновляет загруженность, постоянно нужно щелкать чтоб он обновлял данные. А можно как-то динамически сделать? чтоб сам обновлял и без щелчков показывал )

Comment: @ceh, можно использовать таймер https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ceh, расширил ответ

Comment: Фуух ну наконец-то сработало как надо, спустя 3 часа  я разобрался :D
Спасибо

Comment: @ceh, Отлично! Рад, что помог)